# Polyominoes to construct alphabet

Tags: polyomino

It is possible, using a set of just 10 polyominoes, to construct any one of the 26 letters below. Can you find such a set?

[image]

When constructing, polyominoes may be rotated and flipped, but may not overlap.

Comment: Whew, that's quite a bit more difficult than the last one!

Comment: You enjoy challenges, right? :)

Comment: Can the tiles overlap?

Comment: @Dmitry No. See last sentence.

Comment: Are triominoes allowed?

Comment: @Alto All polyominoes are allowed.

Comment: @Alto I assume you meant trominoes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I haven't tried one of these before; I just stumbled across the question by accident. But I think I have an answer. You can build all 26 letters if you have a set containing:

> - 1 straight pentomino
>  - 1 straight tetromino
>  - 4 straight trominoes
>  - 2 L-shaped trominoes
>  - 2 dominoes

Image below:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen to know if there are other correct solutions?

Comment: Very nicely done! And yes there are other solutions. My own solution had 3 trominoes and 7 dominoes.

Answer (score 16):

Using:

> **9**. 1 straight tetromino, 2 straight trominoes, 1 L-tromino and 5 dominoes, which is minimal in the sense that it only uses $23$ blocks, which is how many blocks both 'B' and 'R' use.
>
>  [image: letters]

Comment: You haven't shown that this set actually does tile all the letters though. A picture would help.

Comment: You can almost do it with {1,3,5} -- all except K.

Comment: Oh, but it can be done with 9 polyominoes, with an L tromino replacing domino+monomino.

Comment: I think your E, I and S are using one extra domino than you have in your set...

Comment: @Stiv; fixed, tnx.

Comment: Wow! I had a suspicion it could be done with 9 but couldn't make it work. Excellent job! Technically, though, the question asks for a solution with 10, so I feel I should give Dave the checkmark. But really nice find! :)

Comment: Great work! I think this should be the accepted answer. But can it be done in 8?